# Does killing key targets counts as kills?

Tags: dishonored

I am asking this as there is an achievement in Dishonored that is called [Clean Hands](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/Clean_Hands), the question is does killing key targets count? As sometimes there is no choice in the Lady Boyle mission (maybe I haven't found a way yet) I am doing a second playthrough to get the other achievements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Killing key targets will count as kills and will prevent you from getting the '[Clean Hands](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/Clean_Hands)' achivement. All missions, including the '[Lady Boyle's Last Party](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/Lady_Boyle%27s_Last_Party)' mission, have [a non-lethal solution](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/Lady_Boyle%27s_Last_Party#Non-lethal_solution).

Comment: Alright, at least i am doing something right by not killing overseer Campbell in my second playthrough. I do remember that one of the achievements ghost and specter says that not to alert anyone and not kill any character and that does not count towards killing key targets, therefore I was worried about that part.

Answer (score -2):

you will not get the clean hands achievement if you kill key targets use a choke hold with bend time then blink away or do side missions and they will "neutralize" the target and it does not count aginst you... so choke or side missions your choice.

Comment: This question was answered 4 years ago, and you're not adding anything to it.